# How to windows form application to work with Oracle without installing Oracle client at end user pcs

Tags: oracle, winforms, client, end-user

i have an windows Form Application that use with Oracle db 
my Question is it applicable to install application on end user pc without having oracle Client , 
is There is there is any Solution like installing application on server that has oracle client and may end user access application  that exist in the server

Comment: Maybe as published application in Citrix.?

Comment: Thnx for replay ,but I have no idea about what is citrix